# What is the purpose of Local Folders in Kmail and can they be removed?

Tags: kde

Using a fresh install of Kontact under KDE 4.8, I have found that there is a default "Local Folders" Akonadi resource that can not be removed (or rather as soon as it is removed, it is immediately recreated). It automatically points to `~/.local/share/local-mail`, which is a maildir. I am already using a local maildir directory (at `~/.mail`) as a separate Akonadi resource, so I have no need for this pre-created "Local Folders".

There also appears to be a concept of `SpecialCollectionAttributes` in Akonadi to mark certain mail folders as `Inbox`, `Outbox`, `Sent` and so on. Kmail provides no means to change which directories are marked with these "special" flags. In my setup, I can see the need for designating which of my directories should be used for certain purposes.

What I'd like to know is what purpose was envisioned for "Local Folders" and how I can avoid using them in favour of my own designated "special folders".

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If kmail fails to send e-mail it will save it in Local Folders "outbox", not the IMAP outbox. Same thing with sending e-mail, if there's a problem with writing to default sent-mail it will save it in Local Folders.

All in all, inbox, trash, drafts and templates are useless. Outbox and sent-mail are not.

I'd suggest keeping them. Of course you can always redirect in your profile where Inbox, Trash, Drafts, etc. *should* be, but Local Folders remain as a fallback.

Edit: Trash location is defined in Receiving accounts settings. I don't think you can redefine where's outbox. Considering that the mails there should be queued only if you are offline, keeping them in Local Folders is a good idea anyway.

Comment: Before I give you the points, can you tell me where to set the default Outbox and Trash folders? You pointed me towards the Identities settings, where Sent, Drafts and Templates can be changed, but I haven't been able to track down the others.

Comment: @SigueSigueBen added Trash configuration, don't know if you can change outbox (or even if it's a good idea)...

Comment: Perhaps there's been a change in Kmail, since there is no longer an option to set the Trash in the receiving settings. It's a pity that the Local Folders can't be completely replaced by another arbitrary local maildir directory.

Comment: "there is no longer an option to set the Trash" in the Receiving Settings... I am currently running KMail 5.23.3 and in Settings > Accounts > Receiving > (select an account) > Advanced there is a setting for the Trash folder for that receiving account.

Answer (score 1):

You might be interested in a feature request to [hide Local Folders](https://bugs.kde.org/show_bug.cgi?id=165419) in Kmail.

Comment: Seems to be a dormant feature request unfortunately.

Comment: All KDE feature requests stay dormant for four years before they get implemented! I've filed or triaged over 1500 KDE bugs, and if a bug doesn't get fixed in a week, then it will take four years before it gets addressed, on average. But commenting on the bug does in fact help.

Comment: 11 years later...